# Using R ggbio circle function to color each chromosome to have different colors

Tags: r

I had a pretty specific case with using ggbio's circle() function.

Using the genomicranges package I've made a make belief dataset

```
gr <- GRanges(seqnames = 
    c("scaffold_13117","scaffold_6016","scaffold_13335"),
    ranges = IRanges(
        start = rep(1,3),
        end = c(5790199,5827,3335858),
    ),
    strand = rep("*",3),
    n = c("red","blue","red")
)
```

One can use ggbio to plot a circular plot such as

```
p <- ggbio() + circle(gr, geom = "ideo")
```

However I wanted to color each chromosome by the 'n' column of the metadata section. Specifically it should be red for scaffold_13117 and scaffold_13335 but blue for scaffold_6016. I'm wondering how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this (Note I also changed the size of "scaffold_6016" so the blue can be better seen):

```
gr <- GRanges(seqnames = 
    c("scaffold_13117","scaffold_6016","scaffold_13335"),
    ranges = IRanges(
        start = rep(1,3),
        end = c(5790199,5000000,3335858),
    ),
    strand = rep("*",3),
    n = c("red","blue","red")
)

mycolours<-c("red","blue")
names(mycolours)<-mycolours

p<-ggbio() + circle(gr,geom="rect",aes(fill=n))+scale_fill_manual(values=mycolours,guide="none")
print(p)
```